# Spreadsheetgear - how to control tab bar

Tags: spreadsheetgear

When I create a workbook in Spreadsheetgear with multiple worksheets, save it to a file, and open it - the tab bar displays only the last sheet added.  I have to click on the tab bar navigation arrows to get all 4 of the tabs to display.  Does anyone know how to adjust the settings of the tab bar display?

The Excel Macro for scrolling over the workbook tabs to the first position is this:

ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Position:=xlFirst

But, I cannot figure out how to make that happen in Spreadsheetgear.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in SpreadsheetGear 10.0.  It is supposed to be fixed in the next release.  See comment below that I received from support:

> It looks like you are running into a known bug.  SpreadsheetGear is writing out an 
>   incorrect “firstSheet” index, which causes Excel to “scroll” to the corresponding 
>   incorrect spot, all but hiding the rest of the tabs from view.  The scenarios we found 
>   that led to this issue all included both adding and removing/hiding sheets to a workbook 
>   in the same routine, although there could be more scenarios we are unaware of.
>
> We opened up a Work Item to look into fixing this in our next major release, which is 
>   due out very soon—we are likely within a month of a Beta release, although this could slip.